# Pytorch Facenet MTCNN Image output

Tags: python, pytorch, face-recognition, facenet

I am doing a face recognition app using facenet pytorch (https://github.com/timesler/facenet-pytorch) in python using two methods.

**1st method**
Code -

```
resnet = InceptionResnetV1(pretrained='vggface2').eval()
mtcnn = MTCNN(image_size=96)

img = Image.open(image_path)
image_prep = mtcnn(img)
plt.figure()
plt.axis('off')
plt.imshow(image_prep.permute(1, 2, 0))
if image_prep is not None:
  image_embedding = resnet(image_prep.unsqueeze(0))
```

In this code, I extract the face from the given images, and get the 512 encodings for recognizing faces.

In this example, I used two different faces, and plot the distance between the faces

```
        a.jpg       b.jpg
a.jpg   0.000000    1.142466
b.jpg   1.142466    0.000000
```

It works well...

**2nd method**
Code-

```
 img = Image.open(image)
 boxes, probs = mtcnn.detect(img) # Gives the coordinates of the face in the given image
 face = img.crop((boxes[0][0], boxes[0][1], boxes[0][2], boxes[0][3])) # Cropping the face
 plt.figure()
 plt.imshow(face)
 pil_to_tensor = transforms.ToTensor()(face).unsqueeze_(0) # Converting to tensor type
 image_embedding = resnet(pil_to_tensor)
```

In this code, I used to get the coordinates of the face, first and then the embeddings. The distance between the two faces -

```
        a.jpg       b.jpg
a.jpg   0.000000    0.631094
b.jpg   0.631094    0.000000
```

In 1st method, I directly feed the image to the mtcnn and gets better result, the distance between the two faces are more than 1.0.
In, 2nd method, I gets the coordinates of the faces using `mtcnn.detect()`, cropped the face from the given image, and feed to resnet. This method gives less distance between the two different faces.

Then, I find the reason for why the 1st method performs well than the 2nd method by plotting the result(face) before feeding to resnet.

In 2nd method, I feed the faces same as given in the input image(clear image) by cropping the faces using `mtcnn.detect()`.

But, In 1st method, I directly gives the input to `mtcnn(img)` which returns the tensor of the faces in dark than in input image. This darker image is not a clear image(area around eyes are darker, I tested with many photos), Can't able to see the eyes clearly. This is the reason, the 1st method shows higher distance between two faces.

My doubt is, Why mtcnn returns the tensor in dark, How to solve it, Help me in this issue,

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe besause tensor returns in [-1:1] range?
And you have to convert it back to uint8 [0-255].